# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column cons.consrc does not exist

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask

I am working on a web app where I needed to update the Postgres(12) database. I am using flask-migrate for the purpose.

I have tried to fix it, but it seems it is a new issue and hence I am not getting much help. I have tried to modify the database from my terminal, that works obviously. This is what I usually type to update my db:

```py
flask db migrate -m ".."
```

This is the error message I am receiving at the terminal:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column cons.consrc does not exist
LINE 4:                 cons.consrc as src
                        ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "cons.conkey" or the column "cons.conbin".
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I suspect it's related to Postgres 12 specifically, as I updated recently.

Comment: @TomášM. Yes, some GitHub Q&A said the same. Since this is a recent issue, maybe it has not been covered so well.

Comment: Or maybe it warrants opening an issue with SQLAlchemy/psycopg2?

Comment: I have found this < https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4463 >. Have a look, please. @TomášM.

Comment: Yes: downgrade Postgres

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I got the same error after upgrading to Postgres v12.

I did:

```
pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy
```

and upgrade any other dependency packages working together with sqlalchemy, for example, pip install --upgrade vdm

Hope this helps

Comment: I tweaked some SQL query and then the issue was fixed, you can visit the above link.

Comment: I can't update sqlalchemy on my project, any sugestion for solving this problem?

Comment: @PatrickSampaio, not sure where you are encountering this bug. But I encountered it while trying to use `autogenerate`. I resolved it by just setting up another Postgres instance with docker and pointing alembic there to autogenerate the migration.